# In Linux, is it possible that all pages belonged to a user-mode process or a running kernel mode module go to disk?

Tags: linux-kernel, operating-system, kernel, linux-device-driver

I am developing a kernel mode module which reads the whole pages that are available in RAM. I am wondering if I get the list of processes and kernel modules from the RAM image I have created, is it possible to get no trace of an application because all its pages has gone to disk? If no, in there any specific part of applications (user-mode and kernel-mode) that will never become paged out?

Answer (score 0):

There are certainly parts of the kernel that can never be paged: for example, the paging code. Unless a process has locked a page in memory the entire process can be paged out.

Comment: Thanks. I think no part of OS code will be paged out in Linux. Does what you said work for kernel modules? I mean an entire kernel module can be paged out?

Answer (score 0):

No part of the kernel can be paged or swapped, because the kernel runs in *real* memory. Paging and swapping are terms from *virtual* memory management, which applies only to programs running in userspace.

Loadable kernel modules (LKMs), once they are loaded, are *part of* the kernel, so no, they can't be paged or swapped.

However, in answer to your question, yes, a process running in user space could conceivably have all of its memory paged/swapped to disk, but it's unlikely that every single page gets paged out at once, unless the process has been idle on a busy system.